# Best 'classic' RDoc version?

Tags: rdoc

I would like to generate the classic 4-panel, framed RDoc format, with working hyperlinks. Any suggestions of which RDoc to install?

My ruby 1.8.6 installation has an RDoc that generates the 4-panel format, but files aren't hyperlinked. My ruby 1.9.2 installation generates the non-frame Darkfish format, which is not what I want. I've tried installing older versions of RDoc in my 1.9.2 installation, but somehow I always get Darkfish format. Is there an rdoc command flag I should be using to prevent that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Fivefish RDoc generator](https://github.com/ged/rdoc-generator-fivefish). It should work as follows:

```
gem install rdoc-generator-fivefish 
rdoc -f fivefish lib/ ext/ *.md # get all the files in your project
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

rdoc accepts a template parameter that lets you override the template as described at http://www.davidpierron.com/index.php/archives/2009/03/09/255/.

I couldn't get his solution to work for the Rails docs though.